# finding limit of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

I want to find the limit of $\dfrac{x^2 +y^4}{y^2+x^4}$  as $(x,y) \to (\infty, \infty)$.

I tried two different paths:

- $y=x$: We have the limit of the above function $\lim (x^2+x^4)/(x^4+x^2)=1$,
- $y=2x$: We have $\lim (x^2+16x^4)/(x^4+4x^2)=16\neq1$.

So I concluded that the limit does not exist.

Is there a better way to find the limit?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Do you suspect your method is incorrect? A faster method? Your method seems correct (a pretty standard way to establish the limit doesn't exist in two dimensions), and it doesn't seem particularly complicated.

Comment: I think, it is the most simplest way to show whether a limit exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct and the limit does not exist.